# Warning in core data database

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have created core data database in xcode. i haven't insert any thing in DB and getting following worning. DipItItemOptions has a relationship with DipItItems entity

DipItItemOptions.newRelationship1 should have an inverse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is recommended that relationships in Core Data work both ways. So if DipItItemOptions has a relationship with DipItItems, then DipItItems should also have a relationship with DipItItemOptions. It's not always necessary but recommended anyway.